# Symfony 2 nginx configuraiton throws 500 error

Tags: php, symfony, nginx

This is my configuration:

```
server {
    server_name domain.com;
    root /var/www/domain.com/web;

    location / {
        # try to serve file directly, fallback to app.php
        try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
    }
    # DEV
    # This rule should only be placed on your development environment
    # In production, don't include this and don't deploy app_dev.php or config.php
    location ~ ^/(app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        # When you are using symlinks to link the document root to the
        # current version of your application, you should pass the real
        # application path instead of the path to the symlink to PHP
        # FPM.
        # Otherwise, PHP's OPcache may not properly detect changes to
        # your PHP files (see https://github.com/zendtech/ZendOptimizerPlus/issues/126
        # for more information).
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
    }
    # PROD
    location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        # When you are using symlinks to link the document root to the
        # current version of your application, you should pass the real
        # application path instead of the path to the symlink to PHP
        # FPM.
        # Otherwise, PHP's OPcache may not properly detect changes to
        # your PHP files (see https://github.com/zendtech/ZendOptimizerPlus/issues/126
        # for more information).
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        # Prevents URIs that include the front controller. This will 404:
        # http://domain.tld/app.php/some-path
        # Remove the internal directive to allow URIs like this
        internal;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/domain.com.error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/domain.com.access.log;
}
```

The mail website works, `domain.com/`, but whenever I open any other route like `domain.com/test/` I get 500 internal server error.

Also, when I open dev environment like `domain.com/app_dev.php/test/` I get an error saying that I can't access `app_dev.php` file.

What's wrong?

Comment: It might work as it's an official nginx configuration from [symfony.com](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html#nginx), so could you provide some more information about your application, for example your controller and `routing.yml` file? What about `app_dev.php` — access to this file is closed from not localhost for security reasons, you can look the code yourself and even remove the protection if you need.

Comment: Also you can look through your logs: `/var/log/nginx/domain.com.error.log` and `/var/www/domain.com/app/logs/prod.log` for more information.

Comment: Logs are empty - both in application, and nginx. It's like nothing at all happens when I enter any route.

Comment: I didn't touch the routing config, I've just been adding annotations - it worked on my local apache machine. What other info can I provide?

Comment: That's very strange. I think you are to check some more common things. Let's create a chat for simplifying the discussion.

Comment: I created specific chat room: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93343/symfony-2-nginx-configuraiton-throws-500-error

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
server {
listen                *:80;

server_name           time.dev www.time.dev;
client_max_body_size 1m;

root /var/www/time/web;
   index  app_dev.php;

access_log            /var/log/nginx/xxx_time.access.log;
error_log             /var/log/nginx/xxx_time.error.log;

location ~ \.php$ {

  root  /var/www/time/web;
  fastcgi_index app_dev.php;
  fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /app_dev.php$is_args$args;
  include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;

  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
  fastcgi_param APP_ENV dev;

}
location / {
    root  /var/www/time/web;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /app_dev.php$is_args$args;
    autoindex off;
    index  index.html index.htm index.php;


  }
  sendfile off;
}
```

It's copied from my vagrant dev machine.

https://gist.github.com/sfarkas1988/f781ef3015f7d794b6b2

Comment: Please explain why your configuration is better than the official.